# How is it possible that a SpriteKit dynamic Body can tunnel through a StaticBody?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, tunneling

Hi I am getting a weird effect in my `SpriteKit` game.

I have a wall around the screen, 
which I had created `staticbody` by using `bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect`.

By doing `skView.showsPhysics = YES;` all bodies are also shown in the screen.

I have a ball in screen. Which having `dynamic body`.
sometime when I do provide `Force` to ball it pass throgh that static wall!!!

How is this possible??

Though I can see both bodies on screen, the dynamic ball sometime passes through the static wall.

I also given `usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;` property to both `physics bodies`.
But it doesn't prevent this issue.

How can I prevent this issue?

Comment: This can happen if the `collisionBitMask` is not set correctly or you apply too much force.

Comment: I think collisionBitMask is already set properly, If i didn't set it properly then this kind of scenario should happen every time, But this only happen when velocity of my ball(Dynamic physics body) is high.

Comment: Try applying and impulse instead of a force. Also as a workaround you can manually check the position of the node to prevent it from leaving the bounds of the screen.

Comment: You can add a `SKConstraint` to keep your sprites on the screen. See positionX:Y here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKConstraint_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKConstraint/positionX:Y:

Comment: I will check about SKConstraint and let you knew.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the velocity of an object is extremely high. For example, if your ball object is traveling at a velocity of X + 300 for each frame, then chances are it will not detect a "wall" and move past it.

Setting usesPreciseCollisionDetection to YES will not solve this if the velocity is too high.

You should apply a speed limit to your object's velocity. Something like this:

```
if(self.physicsBody.velocity.dx > 100)
    self.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(100, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
```

The above limits the right movement of your object to 100 while leaving the dy (up & down) velocity as is.